# Calculate decimals input piped to awk using two values which both occur on different rows and repeat every nth row?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have input piped to awk on a macOS system. I want the sum of two decimal values. One occurs every second row, the other is on every fourth row. I want the  result of the sum on every fifth row. The values are delimited by colon+space before, and a comma after. Every sixth row is empty. This pattern repeats until end of the input.

```
BB: 728345643856359022, 
SH: 3560836, 
RJ: 1500369, 
DD: 1403849, 
Total:,

BB: 729586953244932948, 
SH: 8560836, 
RJ: 4700360, 
DD: 3403021, 
Total:,

BB: 821334125345384020, 
SH: 5293431, 
RJ: 2642499, 
DD: 2433292, 
Total:,
```

If relevant, `which awk` outputs `/usr/bin/awk` and `brew list --version` outputs `gawk 5.2.1_1`. Is this possible in g/awk? Any advice appreciated!

To format the input I am using:

```
getlist | awk '{print $1 $2}' \
| grep 'BB\|SH\|RJ\|DD' \
| sed 's/"//g' \
| awk '{print;} NR % 4 == 0 { print "Total:,";}' \
| awk '{print;} NR % 5 == 0 { print "";}' \
| awk '{print $1 $2}'
```

**Expected output**

```
BB: 728345643856359022, 
SH: 3560836, 
RJ: 1500369, 
DD: 1403849, 
Total: 4964685,

BB: 729586953244932948, 
SH: 8560836, 
RJ: 4700360, 
DD: 3403021, 
Total: 11963857,

BB: 821334125345384020, 
SH: 5293431, 
RJ: 2642499, 
DD: 2433292, 
Total: 7726723,
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I have edited to include expected output.

Comment: and explanation of pipe.

Comment: Should we assume you're on macOS?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to not specifically limit any help to macOS solutions which is why I highlighted gawk or awk on my system.

Comment: Makes sense. But the versions of even standard tools like `grep` that are available are different on different systems, so knowing your OS is often essential for ensuring that the commands actually work for you. Admittedly, not in this case, but better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's simplify your pipeline a little. I don't know what output `getlist` produces, but based on what you show, this will be equivalent with the minor change of not adding the `Total` line since that is only making it harder to parse and we will be adding it later:

```
getlist | 
 tr -d '"' |
 awk '/BB|SH|RJ|DD/{print $1 $2}; NR % 5 == 0 { print ""}'
```

You can break lines at `|`, no need for `\` . And you can merge all of the steps into a single `awk`, and use `tr` instead of `sed` for brevity (and likely speed although the difference will be minimal here).

With this in mind, we can extend your `awk` a little to get the remaining piece:

```
getlist | 
 tr -d '",' |
 awk '/BB|SH|RJ|DD/{
        print $1 $2","; 
        if(/SH/){ sh = $2 } 
        if(/DD/){ printf "Total: %d,\n", sh + $2 }
      }
      NR % 5 == 0 { print ""}'
```

Note that I added `,` to the characters that `tr` is removing to facilitate numerical operations (`,` isn't a number), so I am also adding it back in the various `print` calls in awk.

---

In case I have misunderstood, here is a way to do the same thing using the output you already have from your original pipeline (I saved your example as `file`):

```
$ awk '{ 
         if(!/Total/){print; 
           if(/SH/){ sh = $2 } 
           if(/DD/){ val = sh + $2 }
         }
         else{
            print "Total:",val","
         }
        }' file
BB: 728345643856359022, 
SH: 3560836, 
RJ: 1500369, 
DD: 1403849, 
Total: 4964685,

BB: 729586953244932948, 
SH: 8560836, 
RJ: 4700360, 
DD: 3403021, 
Total: 11963857,

BB: 821334125345384020, 
SH: 5293431, 
RJ: 2642499, 
DD: 2433292, 
Total: 7726723,
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The solution works exactly for my needs. I can see that I could have made the question clearer by showing the input, which may have helped to explain my messy piping.  Thanks for the notes about that!  One side question. When I ran the code, I substituted sed and tr. tr does indeed seem faster. I'm pretty new to unix commands, what is tr?

Comment: Regarding `I could have made the question clearer by showing the input` - isn't that block of text at the top of your question the output from `getlist` (whatever that is) and so the input to the script you're trying to write?

Comment: @XJMZX Briefly, it stands for "translate" and is used to, well, translate between one set of characters and another. In this case, I'm using the `-d` flag which instead deletes characters. It is one of the core utilities, should be available on pretty much any *nix system and, like all *nix tools, is designed to do one thing very fast and very well. See `man tr` for more. By the way, if one of the answers here helped you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left.

Comment: Yes.`getlist` is substituting a command which parses a long json-format to my pipeline. There were many rows. As someone asked below, why it's harder for me to use read .file solution. I'm just starting with grep, awk, sed syntax. If I showed the raw json (before pipe) that might have helped you all understand the pipeline @EdMorton

Comment: Oh, this is JSON!? Yes, there are dedicated tools (e.g. `jq`) to parse JSON data on the command line and trying to do it with general purpose tools like sed and awk is sometimes easier, but more often is actually harder and is always more fragile and likely to break. So yes, next time, please post the original output when asking.

Comment: Appreciate the explaination @terdon

Comment: Yes, showing us the real input would have helped tremendously. You may want to ask a new question with that after accepting an answer to the question you asked here.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll consider doing that if it seems appropriate to @EdMorton

Comment: Well, the input is json formatted, but I'm actually using grep/awk/sed/tr etc because I'm working out how to process and format text with these tools, later I will format for toml format output. Not sure whether jq would be suitable for this? Thanks again for your time and help @terdon

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: and even if you didn't use jq, you never need grep, sed, and/or tr when you're using awk., e.g. `tr -d '",' | awk 'foo'` = `awk '{gsub(/[",]/,"")} foo'`. You also don't need to pipe one call of awk to a second call of awk.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have tag-value pairs in your data as you have, I find it best to first create an array of those mappings (`m[]` below) and then you can get any value just by indexing the array with the associated name. Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F': *' -v OFS=': ' '{m[$1]=$2} $1=="Total"{$2=(m["SH"] + m["DD"])","} 1' file
BB: 728345643856359022,
SH: 3560836,
RJ: 1500369,
DD: 1403849,
Total: 4964685,

BB: 729586953244932948,
SH: 8560836,
RJ: 4700360,
DD: 3403021,
Total: 11963857,

BB: 821334125345384020,
SH: 5293431,
RJ: 2642499,
DD: 2433292,
Total: 7726723,
```

Comment: That's a very useful explanation. As I commented in other's solutions, I'm learning how to use awk and it's still difficult to test different solutions with pipeline. Thanks for the useful advice.

Comment: You're welcome but I can't imagine why input from a pipe `command | awk 'script'` would be any more difficult to handle than input from a file `awk 'script' file`.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I was avoiding using read from file until the end of text-processing. But I see your point, there's not a huge mental transformation between the two constructions. Please understand, with every helpful explanation I'm closer to writing my own working scripts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, which takes your existing output and achieves the new desired output.  Works fine with gawk 5.1.0 here.

```
$ awk '/^SH/{a=$2}/^DD/{b=$2}/^Total/{$0="Total: "a+b","}1' input.txt
BB: 728345643856359022,
SH: 3560836,
RJ: 1500369,
DD: 1403849,
Total: 4964685,

BB: 729586953244932948,
SH: 8560836,
RJ: 4700360,
DD: 3403021,
Total: 11963857,

BB: 821334125345384020,
SH: 5293431,
RJ: 2642499,
DD: 2433292,
Total: 7726723,
$
```

Comment: FYI it'll behave the same way in any awk.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution. I'm unable to get it working with the pipeline. I should have added this more explicitly but I will see if I can get it working and comment again.

Comment: Thatmightbeeasiertoreadifyouusedafewspaces :-)